# How to update state directly after calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the number of pages in a pagination by getting the number of products from my API & storing this number in the state.

This is my code:

```
class AdminProducts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          page: 1,
        };
        this.onPageChange = this.onPageChange.bind(this);

        this.product = new Products();


        this.calculateNumberOfPages = this.calculateNumberOfPages.bind(this); 
      }
      componentWillMount(){
        this.product.getProductsAmount().then(
            (val) => this.calculateNumberOfPages(val)
        );
      }

      async calculateNumberOfPages(_total_amount_products){
            // console.log(_total_amount_products); 
            await this.setState({total: Math.ceil(_total_amount_products/9)});  
      }

      onPageChange(page) {
          console.log(page); 
        this.setState({page: page});
      }

    render(){
        return(
            <Col md={10}>
                <Row>

                <Col md={12}>
                    <div className='float-right'> 
                        {console.log(this.state.total)}
                        <UltimatePagination 
                            currentPage={this.state.page} 
                            totalPages={this.state.total} 
                            onChange={this.onPageChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Col>
                </Row>

            </Col> 

        )
    }
}
```

this.products is a sepperate class which class the a **async** method get in my API class.

The problem is that the state isn't updated before the component is loaded. How can I update the state before rendering the component or how can I wait for the async call of the setState method to finish

Comment: You want force component to wait with rendering until your async function is done?

Comment: @Kinduser the goal is that the variable total has a value upon rendering. Otherwise my pagination can't be created

Comment: [`this.setState()` accepts a callback function as a second param](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: @ArmanCharan I know that it accepts a callback function but what do I need to do with it. Create my component inside a function? Store it in state after that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can do the similar by set a state calling `isFetching`. When you got product on API, just set isFetching to false and render. if `isFetching is true` you can display a spinner or display nothing. here is examplate

```
this.state = {
   page: 1,
   isFetching: true,
};

componentWillMount(){
   this.product.getProductsAmount().then(
      (val) => this.calculateNumberOfPages(val);
      this.setState({isFetching: flase});
   );
}
```

in render

```
render(){
   if(this.state.isFetching) {
      return <div/>
   }
   return(
      <Col md={10}>
        ....
   )
}
```